# Shortest ways in a grid above the angle bisector

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Suppose, you have a grid with the side lengths n and m and the angle bisector from the upper left corner to the bottom side. To walk along the lines from A to B, there are $\binom{n + m}{n}$ shortest ways, which means, that you can only go leftward or downward. This should be quite logical.
[image: Grid with angle bisector]

However, if you are only allowed to walk above the angle bisector, the formula is 
$\binom{n + m}{n} - \binom{n + m}{n + 1}$
What is the proof for this equation?

Comment: See [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof) of the case in which $m=n$; you should be able to modify it to cover the more general setting.